# XMPP OPENFIRE Index page is blank after login

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Admin console is listening at http://localhost:9090 and when I try to login it goes to index.jsp page but that page is blank, what could be reason.

server is connected to database and successfully configured and added tables in database. Using Windows OS, and database is MYSQL which is running at local host port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and than I downloaded Open fire 3.9.2 and followed steps at this link and it worked for me. https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1200 
before this I was using 3.9.3.